# Why is it taking so much longer than it used to for MathJax to get rendered?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

These last few days when I click on a posting it sometimes takes more than a minute or even two, for MathJax to get rendered. It used to be a couple of seconds.

Is anything being done to correct this?

Comment: Do you have specific examples? What kind of browser, operating system, and device are you using? Have you tried using a different browser? A different operating system? A different device? Have you tried using incognito mode? Have you cleared your cache? Have you restarted your browser? Your device? Have you been experiencing this all over the internet or just on MO? Please include this information when submitting bug reports.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have been struggling with this problem too. First I thought there is something wrong with my internet connection, but further tests proved me wrong. I mainly work with the Edge browser on windows 10, but observed a similar trend on firefox. The font rendering takes much longer than before, and sometimes it doesn't load at all. see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMhSq.png) for example

Comment: @polfosol Is that happening everywhere where MathJax is heavily used or just MO? Or just SE? What font render are you using on MathJax and does it get better if you change that setting?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows 10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I did some more tests. So far I haven't faced the same issue with the pages that heavily use mathjax and are _not_ on the SE network. It seems this problem only persists when I am visiting MO and MSE pages that have a lot of math text. Those pages that are not heavily filled with math still have a little lag, but they render the font correctly. What I found strange is two things: 1) this is a fairly recent problem and started a few months ago. 2) It is odd that nobody has noticed it so far and _almost_ no one else had the same issue.

Comment: When comparing with other sites, perhaps one should take into account also version of MathJax which is used. See also: [Are there plans to switch to the current version of MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385913)

Comment: I may have noticed this ... MacOS ... but it is not as bad as the OP's case.  For me: before, the render delay for MathJax was not noticeable, but now it is perhaps $5$ or $10$ seconds.